# How to use Lua to parse a Property file

Tags: properties, lua, lua-table

I need help on a small Lua script that needs to parse a property file and generate an array using string key. Here's what I tried to do;

```
file = assert(io.open("/root/test.prop", "r"))
property = {}
for line in file:lines() do
  for key, value in string.gmatch(line, "(.-)=(%w+)") do 
    property[key] = value 
  end
end
```

For some unknown reason only the first pair of key value is added to the table. Since I,m new to Lua, can somebody give an hint.

Comment: What's the format of the file?

Comment: Please show us a sample file.

Comment: Since you're reading the file line by line I guess this should suffice: `key, value = string.match(line,"(.-)=(.-)$"); property[key] = value`.

Answer (score 0):

Likely your gmatch is failing on the second line and so the key value is nil, and so the for loop will quit.

As someone else mentioned, use a more encompassing match expression such as "(.-)=(.-)$".